# Windows 7: file system delays

Tags: windows-7, filesystems

Recently my Windows 7 machine has been experiencing delays when I manually create folders, rename files, move files and so on.

For example, if I double click on a folder, and within that window: right click > new > folder, it takes about 5-10 seconds for the "New Folder" icon to appear. And it used to appear instantly with the name "New Folder" selected for renaming, but now I have to manually choose to edit the name (i.e. single click, or right-click > rename). And there are similar delays for making new files, moving them etc. One solution is hitting F5, but it's a real pain when I'm doing a lot of file manipulation.

Any idea what's causing this? And how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to trace the delay. Filter for explorer.exe and look at the duration tab.

Here are 2 videos how to use it:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-3-Process-Monitor

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor